# can nagios adjust its check time based on the status info?

Tags: nagios

(I suspect the answer is "No", but I'll ask anyway.)

I have puppet installed on my systems, and puppet runs every half hour.  Nagios is checking those puppet logs, also running every half hour, and returns something like this:

```
OK: Puppet agent "2.7.26" running catalogversion 1474549502, and last executed at Fri 23 Sep 2016 18:04:17 GMT
```

The problem is, if puppet checks this service at (let's say) 18:25, and returns the above response, then I won't see any reference to the expected 18:34 puppet run until nagios checks again at 18:55.

I would really like it if nagios could look at the status info, see that this machine ran puppet at 18:04, and reschedule its next check to occur, say, five minutes after the expected next-run.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/passivechecks.html

Comment: @dmourati Thanks for the tip.  It looks like the question then becomes "Can I tell puppet to submit a passive check to nagios whenever it runs?" which may not be any better, but at least gives me another avenue to check.

Comment: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/configuration.html#postruncommand

Comment: @dmourati Wow.  Thanks.  I'll definitely follow up on this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use the value of the return to actually set the next check. 
Nagios has two time paramaters governing check times - `check_interval` and `retry_interval`. `check_interval` is used when the service is up and `retry_interval` is used when the service is not up.  So in a sense you can use the return code to adjust the retry time, but not to a specific clock time.